# Передать дату в Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firestore

Есть база в `Firestore`. Если создавать в ней документы вручную, то можно выбрать объект `Timestamp`. При получении можно просто явно объявить его `Date`

```
Date date = (Date) doc.get("date")
```

Однако, при передаче объекта с `Date` внутри. он автоматически преобразовывает его в `String`, что вызывает ошибку при парсинге из базы. Например,

```
Someobject object = new Someobject(new Date());
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("somecollection")
                                .add(object);
```

после выполнения операции в базе будет документ с полем типа `String` и значением в нем "Nov 29, 2017 24:04".

Конечно, мне бы хотелось хранить дату именно как объект `Timestamp` в базе, чтобы сортировать по ней при получении и хранить в приложении именно как `Date`. Может, кто-то уже сталкивался с такой пролемой - заставить `Firestore` при добавлении данных создавать `Timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего подобного, Firestore без проблем сохраняет Date в поле типа **Timestamp**. Попробуйте сохранить свой объект по-другому.

```
HashMap<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<>();
entry.put("date",new Date());
db.document(somedoc).set(entry);
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Испульзуя метод, указанный в официальной документации (который я честно проигнорировал и решил делать как в Firebase) передается уже Timestamp, а не String. Спасибо.